# How can we "Internationalize" static information that is stored in a SQL Server 2012 table

Tags: sql-server

One of the functions of our application is that it stores content information for users. The information is one of several different 
content types and the available types are stored in a relational table in SQL Server. Here's the class that is used:

```
public partial class ContentType
{
    public int ContentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

The SQL Server Table that backs up this class has the same fields:

```
CREATE TABLE ContentType (
    [ContentTypeId] INT IDENTITY (0, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50) Not NULL,
    [Version] rowversion,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ContentType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContentTypeId] ASC)
)";
```

We would like to "internationalize" our application. This would mean that amongst other things there 
would be different values for the "Name" field depending on language.

Can anyone give us any suggestions on how this could be done?

Comment: This may be simple or it may be exceptionally complex - it depends on whether `Version` and/or `ModifiedDate` have any interactions with this localization; - i.e. if the default language is English, and someone changes the Chinese `Name`, do any `Version` or `ModifiedDate` columns need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "internationalization".  If you simply need support for a second language in the near to medium term, you can solve that by adding a new column in the table.  Something like `AlternateName`.

Or, if `name` simply needs an associated language, you can solve that by including a `LanguageId` column (referencing an associated `Languages` table).

I'm guessing that you mean something more intense, namely the ability to look at the "name" of a "content" in one of several languages.  I am also assuming that `ModifiedDate` is a database field not related to user content.  If not, then you also need to deal with the internationalization of date formats.

Right now, your table structure has a 1-1 relationship between `ContentTypeId` and `name`.    That relationship has to be modified, because you need a 1-many relationship.  Start with a table of allowed languages.  If you want to use abbreviations instead, go with the international standards ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) for instance).  Your own table, though, would allow you to include other information such as preferred date format and preferred currency symbol.

You need another table, something like `ContentLanguages`, something like:

```
create table ContentLanguages (
    ContentLanguageId int primary key,
    LanguageId int,  /* or a code for human readability */
    Name nvarchar(255),
    ModifiedDate datetime
);
```

You then need to maintain this for multiple languages.

If you have a standard language, you will probably want to ensure that all names appear, say in English.  You could do this by having a business rule that would require content to have an English version before any other version could be added (using a trigger or a business rule in a stored procedure).

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand this is that you want to make more user friendlier for people who don’t know English.

I’d consider keeping database as is but only creating international interface.

For example you can create API people would use instead of direct access to database and make this API international by naming methods, classes and other with appropriate international names.

You can even go with international namespaces such sa Main.Espana.MiCasa and Main.English.MyHouse 
In the background you’ll have one set of methods that would do the actual work and then just create wrappers for different languages.

Another way might be to create different schemas in database and give people access only through those schemas. Use views for reading data and stored procedures for inserting and updating.